# Derby: CONCAT equivalent

Tags: java, derby, javadb

Good day!

What is the equivalent function of Derby/Java DB to the CONCAT function of MySQL?

I tried using CONCAT to Derby but it commits an error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you can concatenate two string with `||`

[Derby Built-in function reference - concatenation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj40899.html)

Comment: No problems. If you think this answer helps, you can accept this answer. [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: `||` is the ANSI standard for string concatenation and will work with nearly all DBMS except MySQL and Microsoft