# Right syntax for concat on derby

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am trying to use `concat` with a Derby database query. But i get syntax error. How can I use `concat` in Derby?

The below code is for search purpose

```
  public ArrayList <Tablearray>ListUsers(String ValToSearch){
  ArrayList <Tablearray> usersList  = new ArrayList <Tablearray>();
  Statement st;
  ResultSet rs;

  try {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        st = con.createStatement();
        String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM ABYP WHERE CONCAT(Id_Search, Tyl, Apothkh, Parathrhseis,Ti) LIKE '%"+ValToSearch+"%'";
       //String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM ABYP WHERE ||CONCAT|| (Id_Search) LIKE '%||"+ValToSearch+"||%'";
        //String searchQuery = "SELECT *FROM ABYP where ID_SEARCH =? ";
        rs = st.executeQuery(searchQuery);
  Tablearray tablearray;
  while (rs.next()){
  tablearray = new Tablearray (
    rs.getString("Id_Search"),
    rs.getString("Tyl"),
    rs.getString("Apothkh"),
    rs.getString("Parathrhseis"),
    rs.getString("Ti")
      );
  usersList.add(tablearray);
  }
  }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return usersList;


  }
```

Comment: Derby uses the SQL standard `||` concatenation operator: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj40899.html

Comment: can i have an example please ??? with my query cause i can't do it i was trying with || but nothing ...tyy

Comment: `WHERE Id_Search||Tyl||Apothkh||Parathrhseis||Ti like ...`

Comment: Syntax error: Encountered "Id_Search" at line 1, column 33.                 "SELECT * FROM ABYP WHERE concat Id_Search||Tyl||Apothkh||Parathrhseis||Ti LIKE '%"+ValToSearch+"%'";

Comment: String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM ABYP WHERE concat (Id_Search||Tyl||Apothkh||Parathrhseis||Ti) LIKE '%"+ValToSearch+"%'";  that works but he tell me that Cannot convert types 'INTEGER' to 'VARCHAR'. so ?? how i can make it use for interger ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derby: CONCAT equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203863/derby-concat-equivalent)

Comment: You may be able to use `CAST` on the integer to convert it to a string.